# Optimized code for two string compare in if condition

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

I want to do two string compare and used two different if condition. Is there any better way to do string compare in one if condition

```
if (strcmp(Buff1(), Config1) == 0)
{ 
    if (strcmp(Buff2, Config2) == 0)
    {
      // my code goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. Use `&&` operator.

Comment: @haccks, makes no difference. No assembler instruction will be saved.

Comment: `Buff1` is a function and `Buff2` is a string?

Comment: @SouravGhosh; `Buff1` can return a `char` pointer.

Comment: @haccks It can, but all we're doing here now is assumption. :)

Comment: Don't use `char*` and `strcmp` in C++ unless you really know why you have to use them. Otherwise, remove the C++ tag.

Comment: Not related, but having a variable called `Buff1` and a function called `Buff2` is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent code is:

```
if ((strcmp(Buff1(), Config1) == 0)) &&
    (strcmp(Buff2, Config2) == 0))
{
    // my code goes here
}
```

**Note:** The compiler should generate the same machine code for both code samples. The difference is cosmetic and primarily aimed at the reader of the code.

You do get a difference when you add `else` clauses:

```
if (strcmp(Buff1(), Config1) == 0)
{ 
    if (strcmp(Buff2, Config2) == 0)
    {
      // my code goes here
    }
    else 
    {
        // else 1
    }
}
else 
{
    // else 2
}
```

Compared to:

```
if ((strcmp(Buff1(), Config1) == 0)) &&
    (strcmp(Buff2, Config2) == 0))
{
    // my code goes here
}
else 
{
    // Single else clause
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Klas's answer(just in case you're not familiar with the AND operator) - the AND operator ('&&') checks the first condition and it continues to check the second condition -only if- the first condition is true.
So in your specific question, it checks if the first couple of strings are equal and only if true (are equal), it checks if the second couple are also equal.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious optimization (not mentioned yet), if you know anything about those strings, is to first perform the compare that is more likely to fail.